# Visual Studio 2015 Report Viewer 11

Tags: visual-studio-2015, reportviewer

After doing a fresh install of Windows 10 on a new hard drive and installing Visual Studio 2015 two of our development machines can no longer debug reports with subreports.

We have one machine that was updated to Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2015 without doing a fresh install and we can still debug reports using that machine.  This machine does still have Visual Studio 2013 but our DLLs referenced for ReportViewer are inside a packages folder in our project so all machines should be using the same DLLs.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The two machines that were fresh installs are probably missing the report viewer runtimes like on the 2013 machine.. You could try manually downloading and installing the ReportViewer 2015 runtimes on those two machines. [ReportViewer 2015 Runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45496)